# CSS :read-only selector - Disrupts :disabled in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I experience, that adding a CSS selector including :read-only will make the other CSS selectors not work in Internet Explorer.

```css
textarea {
  margin: 5px;  
}

textarea.ok_class:disabled, 
textarea.ok_class:disabled {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

textarea.not_ok_class:read-only,
textarea.not_ok_class:disabled,
textarea.not_ok_class:disabled {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="ta_1" disabled class="ok_class">Without read-only 1</textarea>
<br>
<textarea name="ta_2" disabled class="ok_class">Without read-only 2</textarea>
<br>
<textarea name="ta_3" disabled class="not_ok_class">With read-only 1</textarea>
<br>
<textarea name="ta_4" disabled class="not_ok_class">With read-only 2</textarea>
```

With the above, the border is **not** red for the disabled textareas with the not_ok_class class.

This is only a problem in Internet Explorer (tested in v. 11). In Chrome it is working as expected.

Removing the line *textarea.not_ok_class:read-only,* will make it work in IE.

Why is the :read-only pseudo selector disrupting the other CSS selectors? 
What am i missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that IE doesn't understand the `:read-only` selector and instead of simply ignoring that one selector it invalidates the entire block.

A workaround is to separate the `:read-only` selector into it's own block. This seems a bit pointless, but it's the only way you're going to get IE to not proceed to invalidate the `:disabled` selectors as well:

```css
textarea {
  margin: 5px;  
}

textarea.ok_class:disabled, 
textarea.ok_class:disabled {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

textarea.not_ok_class:read-only {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

textarea.not_ok_class:disabled,
textarea.not_ok_class:disabled {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="ta_1" disabled class="ok_class">Without read-only 1</textarea>
<br>
<textarea name="ta_2" disabled class="ok_class">Without read-only 2</textarea>
<br>
<textarea name="ta_3" disabled class="not_ok_class">With read-only 1</textarea>
<br>
<textarea name="ta_4" disabled class="not_ok_class">With read-only 2</textarea>
```

Comment: I already tested this as a possible solution...but hoped for an alternative to avoid duplicating CSS :-)

Thanks for the answer anyway...and for the swift reply

Comment: @Brøgger unfortunately I don't think you're going to be able to have both `:read-only` and `:disabled` in the same group of selectors if you want IE11 support.